# How can I draw an image in xml, but change the dimensions in the java class?

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to be able to change the width and height of the bluerect, but it doesn't change when I do an animation.  The dimensions stay the same.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bluerect"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:src="@drawable/bluerect"

    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

Also, I want to be able to draw a rectangle, but declare the dimensions in the java class.  How would I be able to do that?

Comment: Where is the code for the animation?

Comment: ImageView img_animation = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bluerect);

        ScaleAnimation fade_in =  new ScaleAnimation(0f, 1f, 0f, 1f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        fade_in.setDuration(1000);     // animation duration in milliseconds
        fade_in.setFillAfter(true);    // If fillAfter is true, the transformation that this animation performed will persist when it is finished.
        img_animation.startAnimation(fade_in);
        shrink = false;

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your Question, you want to shrink/grow your rectangle dynamically at runtime. Here is my draft for a possible solution:

In my Layout-Xml file, I add two buttons grow and shrink, where I can trigger a 10%growth/shrink animation:

```
<Button
    android:text="Grow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/grow"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<Button
    android:text="Skrink"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/shrink"
    android:layout_below="@+id/grow"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/grow"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/grow"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/grow"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/grow"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bluerect"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:src="@drawable/bluerect"
    android:layout_below="@+id/shrink1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="46dp" />
```

In the class with the respective activity, I declare the following fields:

```
private Button grow;
private Button shrink;
private ImageView img_animation;
private float startdim[] = {1f, 1f};
private float enddim[] = {1f, 1f};
```

This are three fields to store the handle to the two button and the imageview, and two arrays to store the data about the dimensions at the start and the end of the animation.

In the OnCreate method I add the following lines:

```
grow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.grow);
shrink = (Button) findViewById(R.id.shrink);
img_animation = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bluerect);
if (grow != null) grow.setOnClickListener(this);
if (shrink != null) shrink.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Here I get the handle to the buttons and the imageview and set the current class as the Implementer of the OnClickListener.

Next I have encapsulated your animationcode in the method makeanimation:

```
private void makeAnimation(boolean shrink){
    if (shrink){
        enddim[0] -= 0.1f;
        enddim[1] -= 0.1f;
    }
    else{
        enddim[0] += 0.1f;
        enddim[1] += 0.1f;
    }
    ScaleAnimation fade_in = new ScaleAnimation(startdim[0], enddim[0], startdim[1], enddim[1],
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    fade_in.setDuration(1000); // animation duration in milliseconds
    fade_in.setFillAfter(true); // If fillAfter is true, the transformation that this animation performed will persist when it is finished.
    if (img_animation != null) {
        img_animation.startAnimation(fade_in);
        startdim[0] = enddim[0];
        startdim[1] = enddim[1];
    }
}
```

At last I overwrite the OnClick method to get the buttonclicks:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(grow == v){
        makeAnimation(false);
    }
    if(shrink == v){
        makeAnimation(true);
    }
}
```